# android large text size isn't calculated correctly

Tags: java, android, text, text-size

I have this code to measure the text width.

```
public float textWidthPixels(String text) {
    TextPaint textPaint = myAccountView.getPaint();
    float width = textPaint.measureText(text);

    View parent = (View) myAccountView.getParent();
    int paddingLeft = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    int paddingRight = parent.getPaddingRight();

    return width - (paddingLeft + paddingRight);

  }
```

which is called from

```
final ViewTreeObserver[] viewTreeObserver = {myAccountView.getViewTreeObserver()};
viewTreeObserver[0].addOnPreDrawListener(
    new OnPreDrawListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onPreDraw() {
```

however

When i change the font size to large in accessibility menu,

the text width change but not accurately (it says the text width is smaller than the view it's in, but it's actually larger than the view)

Comment: Where are you calling this method? Has everything been rendered already?

Comment: i call on `viewTreeObserver.onPreDraw()`

Comment: @pskink but how do i get the sp in code? `    float width = textPaint.measureText(text);` returns px.

Comment: @pskink i have doubled check and 
the text width change but not accurately (it says the text width is smaller than the view it's in, but it's actually larger than the view)